How to make a Flexbox element fill the remaining vertical space?

I want #item-3 to fill the remaining vertical space.
I cannot modify #root, #item-1, or #item-2. Only #item-3 can be changed.
For performance reasons, I would like to solve this problem using only CSS without relying on JavaScript.

I am trying to make an element fill the remaining vertical space in a Flexbox layout without affecting other elements. Below is my current HTML and CSS:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: gray;
    }

    #root {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-grow: 1;
      align-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 100% !important;
      background-color: green;
    }

    #item-1 {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      align-self: flex-start;
      width: 40%;
      min-width: 100px;
      max-height: 100% !important;
    }

    #item-2 {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      align-self: flex-start;
      width: 60%;
      min-width: 100px;
      max-height: 100% !important;
    }

    #item-3 {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      align-self: flex-start;
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 100px;
      max-height: 100% !important;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="item-1">Dynamic content with uncertain height 1</div>
    <div id="item-2">Dynamic content with uncertain height 2</div>
    <div id="item-3">Dynamic content with uncertain height 3</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




To make #item-3 fill the remaining vertical space in a Flexbox layout, use flex: 0 0 100% to span its own row, align-self: stretch to stretch vertically, and height: calc(100% - max-content) to fill the leftover space dynamically.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: gray;
    }

    #root {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-grow: 1;
      align-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 100% !important;
      background-color: green;
    }

    #item-1 {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      align-self: flex-start;
      width: 40%;
      min-width: 100px;
      max-height: 100% !important;
    }

    #item-2 {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      align-self: flex-start;
      width: 60%;
      min-width: 100px;
      max-height: 100% !important;
    }

    #item-3 {
      flex: 0 0 100%; /* Force full width */
      align-self: stretch; /* Stretch vertically */
      height: calc(100% - max-content); /* Fill remaining height */
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="item-1">Dynamic content with uncertain height 1</div>
    <div id="item-2">Dynamic content with uncertain height 2</div>
    <div id="item-3">Dynamic content with uncertain height 3</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




at least run the snippet to notice that nothing is working ...
